# Please help me speedup my Ubuntu 12

Tags: 12.04, performance, spotify, top, cassandra

```
top - 08:28:09 up 12:59,  2 users,  load average: 0.59, 0.47, 0.35
Tasks: 200 total,   1 running, 199 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.1%us,  2.7%sy,  0.0%ni, 88.1%id,  2.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3981656k total,  3817680k used,   163976k free,   145792k buffers
Swap:  8910840k total,    25940k used,  8884900k free,   632852k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
 1784 cassandr  20   0 2828m 1.4g  16m S    6 35.7   1:18.35 jsvc               
 5250 dev       20   0 1537m 195m  47m S    6  5.0   4:19.77 spotify            
 1202 root      20   0  307m 188m  16m S    4  4.8   2:05.38 Xorg               
 2972 dev       20   0 1501m 368m  29m S    3  9.5   1:52.79 compiz             
 5274 dev       20   0  586m  17m  10m S    1  0.4   0:02.33 gnome-terminal     
 2944 dev       20   0 28020 3712  608 S    1  0.1   0:03.83 dbus-daemon        
 2981 dev        9 -11  421m 5864 3612 S    0  0.1   0:15.76 pulseaudio         
 3005 dev       20   0  628m  15m  10m S    0  0.4   0:00.17 nm-applet          
 3083 dev       20   0  388m  10m 7100 S    0  0.3   0:02.48 bamfdaemon         
 5485 root      20   0 17440 1476 1040 R    0  0.0   0:06.14 top                
 6091 dev       20   0  716m  88m  40m S    0  2.3   0:03.06 chrome             
 6255 dev       20   0  925m  76m  28m S    0  2.0   0:02.26 chrome             
    1 root      20   0 24564 2356 1288 S    0  0.1   0:02.40 init               
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd           
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.72 ksoftirqd/0        
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.63 migration/0        
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.12 watchdog/0         
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.46 migration/1        
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.44 ksoftirqd/1        
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.07 watchdog/1         
   13 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset             
   14 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper            
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs          
   16 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 netns
```

My system used to be real fast (Dell Optiplex 745 w 4 GB memory) but now I think that I installed so many applications and that I got that many background processes so that it slows down my system. I'm wondering if you can help me speedup my system, for instance, I recently instsalled the apache project "cassandra" (the datastore app from apache) which was sort of good but it was just a test and I'm suspecting that the cassandra application could be one of some unneccessary applications that I could remove. Could you give me some suggestions how I can improve? Thanks

### Update

I removed cassandra which seem to have helped much. Thanks!

```
$ sudo apt-get remove cassandra
[sudo] password for dev: 
Läser paketlistor... Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd         
Läser tillståndsinformation... Färdig
Följande paket har installerats automatiskt och är inte längre nödvändiga:
  libjna-java jsvc libopts25 ntp libcommons-daemon-java
Använd "apt-get autoremove" för att ta bort dem.
Följande paket kommer att TAS BORT:
  cassandra
0 att uppgradera, 0 att nyinstallera, 1 att ta bort och 0 att inte uppgradera.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer 14,8 MB att frigöras på disken.
Vill du fortsätta [J/n]? J
(Läser databasen ... 664964 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Tar bort cassandra ...
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss240k
Hanterar utlösare för python-support ...
Hanterar utlösare för ureadahead ...
dev@dev-OptiPlex-745:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Läser paketlistor... Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd         
Läser tillståndsinformation... Färdig
Följande paket kommer att TAS BORT:
  jsvc libcommons-daemon-java libjna-java libopts25 ntp
0 att uppgradera, 0 att nyinstallera, 5 att ta bort och 0 att inte uppgradera.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer 2 858 kB att frigöras på disken.
Vill du fortsätta [J/n]? J
(Läser databasen ... 664861 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Tar bort jsvc ...
Tar bort libcommons-daemon-java ...
Tar bort libjna-java ...
Tar bort ntp ...
 * Stopping NTP server ntpd                                              [ OK ] 
Tar bort libopts25 ...
Hanterar utlösare för man-db ...
Hanterar utlösare för doc-base ...
Behandlar 1 removed doc-base file...
Hanterar utlösare för ureadahead ...
Hanterar utlösare för libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
$
```

Now the ouput from top is:

```
top - 02:08:28 up 6 days, 17:49,  2 users,  load average: 2.31, 2.80, 2.08
Tasks: 215 total,   1 running, 210 sleeping,   0 stopped,   4 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.5%us,  9.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 76.9%id,  5.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.7%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3981656k total,  3875928k used,   105728k free,    33972k buffers
Swap:  8910840k total,   739692k used,  8171148k free,  2284296k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
29893 dev       20   0 1210m  56m 8092 S   21  1.5  19:10.28 /usr/bin/deluge    
 1217 root      20   0  424m 187m  16m S    9  4.8 192:14.43 Xorg               
 2657 dev       20   0 1567m 201m  21m S    5  5.2 262:28.26 compiz             
32020 dev       20   0  586m  16m 9808 S    1  0.4   0:00.80 gnome-terminal     
32004 dev       20   0  922m  73m  20m S    1  1.9   0:05.87 chrome             
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:26.38 ksoftirqd/1        
  380 root      20   0 17456 1476 1036 R    0  0.0   0:00.02 top                
    1 root      20   0 24576 1976 1084 S    0  0.0   0:02.60 init               
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.07 kthreadd           
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:40.31 ksoftirqd/0        
    6 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:16.35 migration/0        
    7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:02.00 watchdog/0         
    8 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:04.78 migration/1        
   12 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:01.70 watchdog/1         
   13 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuset             
   14 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper            
   15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S    0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra and Spotify are the only nonessential applications which are taking up any significant amount of CPU, and even then it isn't that much.  You might consider running Spotify minimized so that it doesn't have to update the screen as much, which will also reduce some of the CPU usage of Xorg and compiz; you also might consider using a lighter-weight window manager than compiz, such as Metacity or even switching to Xfce (`apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`) which provides a mature classic-Gnome-like interface without a lot of bloat.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing Cassandra, you could have stopped the Cassandra service or removed Cassandra from the `init.d` entries.